# when to subtract from the range(len(str))

Tags: python

[problem 1](http://codingbat.com/prob/p164876)

[problem 2](http://codingbat.com/prob/p186048)

answers:

```
def cat_dog(str):
  count_cat = 0
  count_dog = 0
  for i in range(len(str)-2):
    if str[i:i+3] == 'dog':
      count_dog += 1
    if str[i:i+3] == 'cat':
      count_cat += 1

  return count_cat == count_dog

def count_code(str):
  count = 0
  for i in range(0, len(str)-3):
    if str[i:i+2] == 'co' and str[i+3] == 'e':
      count += 1
  return count
```

I am confused why sometimes they subtract 2 or 3 from `range(len(str))`. I get why you would subtract 1 since counting starts from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question reads thus:

> Return `True` if the string "cat" and "dog" appear the same number of times in the given string.

Both "cat" and "dog" are strings of length 3, and you want to avoid overstepping the length of the string itself.

The same is true for the second question:

> Return the number of times that the string "code" appears anywhere in the given string, except we'll accept any letter for the 'd', so "cope" and "cooe" count.

Since "code" and its acceptable variants are strings of length 4, we bias this against 3 so that we avoid overstepping the length of the string we're checking.